# What are the best to ways measure latencies from user space to kernel space?

Tags: c, linux, performance, timer, linux-kernel

I have to measure the latency between a user space program to the driver it interacts with. I basically send a packet through this application. The latecny is between `write` in the user space to corresponding `write` function in the kernel

I used `clock_gettime` with `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` in the user space and
 `getrawmonotonic` in the kernel (driver) and when I see the difference, it is huge (around 4ms). So I am definitely using the wrong approach.

So, what are the best ways to do this?

Comment: Latency between what and what?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Updated the question

Comment: `perf` is a wonderful tool. See e.g. https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: valgrind is quite a well-know linux profiler

Comment: perf and valgrind are excellent tools, as others have mentioned already. strace -T may help too.

Answer (score 0):

To measure just a single context switch from user- to kernel-space, try to use TSC (Time Stamp Counter). It is available on x86 and ARMs, user- and kernel-space.

More info about TSC on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter

BSD-licensed implementation for x86 [could be found here](http://dpdk.org/browse/dpdk/tree/lib/librte_eal/common/include/arch/x86/rte_cycles.h)
and [for 64-bit ARM here.](http://dpdk.org/browse/dpdk/tree/lib/librte_eal/common/include/arch/arm/rte_cycles_64.h)

Also, as comments suggested, consider to use any standard tool available to measure a round-trip latency, i.e. use-to-kernel and back.

Answer (score 0):

If I do this, I would use ftrace， which is a performance tool provided by linux kernel.

It can trace almost all the function in the kernel.

It firstly log the information into a ring buffer in the memory, so it coast very little.

There is a very good document in linux kernel source code "Documentation/trace/ftrace.txt", you also can find it [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/trace/ftrace.txt).

```
1.prepare the environment, configure ftrace.
2.run the application.
3.0.In the application, bind cpu, and give the application priority。
3.1.In the application, write something to the trace_marker, 
3.2.In the application, call the function which you want to test.
4.get the log from the ring buffer.
5.calculate the latency.
```